# Realizing pagination for merged array from multiple data sources (APIs)

Tags: array, wordpress, pagination

I'm improving a WordPress theme with PHP. The theme contains a gallery section which loads data from the Flickr API.

Now the client wants to display Flickr galleries as well as "local" galleries without disclosing where a particular gallery is loaded from.

On page load the theme does a Flickr API request loading 6 galleries. When a "load more" button gets hit, the theme requests 3 more galleries.

I can do exactly the same for for local galleries.

To merge them, I could put them into a unified data structure and order by a "date created" timestamp.

The problem is, after the merge, I don't have any clue how many items come from which data source and which page I need to request from each source when attempting to load more.

I, somehow, need to ensure I'm not leaving out any gallery or display it multiple times. How can I get around this issue? What would be the conceptual ideas you guys would come up with?

**EDIT**

The big problem here is, that I need to work with PHP and cannot store a bunch of entries in an array across requests and load new data if needed. I could only pass a few arguments around, like page numbers, counts; stuff like that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to paginate and combine results that come from different sources sorted](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/279115/how-to-paginate-and-combine-results-that-come-from-different-sources-sorted)

Comment: @cweiske oh, seven and a half years later... :D This was a question specifically about wordpress. I think back then WP stack exchange wasn't a thing, since I asked here. I don't even remember what project that was about or how I solved it. Thank you anyway!